# Selecting the Word after a particular word using RegEx (Regular Expression)

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

In short i am trying to match a word that is after a particular word.

So i have a String that is

```
Name=James  
Age=55  
City=New York
```

Now i want to select everything after the **"Age="** but not including the **"Age="**.

So in short i only want to select **"55"**. There are new line char at the end of each line. Now i've looked at the Lookaround like
`(?!(Age)).*\r`

Which doesn't work.

open to suggestion here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is "positive lookbehind"

```
(?<=your pattern)
```

This looks behind the current location and it needs to match.

So in your case, you want to do:

```
(?<=Age=).*$
```

Comment: Thanks ... I ran the test in Oracle (using REGEXP_SUBSTR), and it still returns null. I even checked a few websites and a Notepad Application with RegExp and it didn't return anything, I quickly knocked something up in Java and it works, so thank you, i am not going crazy

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(?<=Age=).*
```

You have to use a lookbehind.

Be aware that non all the regexes have lookbehind (for example Javascript's one doesn't)

Answer (score 0):

```
"(?<=Age=).*$"

kent$ echo "Name=James  
dquote> Age=55  
dquote> City=New York "|grep -Po "(?<=Age=).*$"
55
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is 
`(?<=Age=)\w+`

\w matches any word character (a-z,0-9)